# how i can access to index from other array into each function

Tags: php, arrays, file

I´m trying to access to my array defined how class variable:

```
$this->allDataLinks
```

This array contain many information with this structure:

```
/**
         *   EXAMPLE DATA THAT ARRIVE TO THIS FUNCTION
         * 
         *   "order" => "PEDIDO#20002 - mundoejecutivo.com.mx"
         *   "order_name" => "mundoejecutivo.com.mx"
         *   "post_url" => "https://mundoejecutivo.com.mx/empresas/empleos-mas-demandados-en-mexico-y-un-enfoque-a-especialistas-en-sap/"
         *   "anchor_text" => "Xamai es partner SAP"
         *   "url" => "https://mx.xamai.com/"
         *   "type_link" => "follow"
*/
```

My array contain 318 reg, so i´m doing a `for` loop and doing a `Goutte\Client` petition.

```
$client = new Client();
$website = $client->request('GET', $data[$i]["post_url"]);
```

Now i need check if in this page contain, `anchor text` and if this `anchor_text` contain this `url` `("url" => "https://mx.xamai.com/")` with this code:

```
for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++){
   $file_headers = @get_headers($data[$i]["post_url"]);
   if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || !strpos($file_headers[0],"200")) {
          $exists = false;
          $access_ko[] = $data[$i]["order"];
   }else{
      $client = new Client();
      $website = $client->request('GET', $data[$i]["post_url"]);
      array_push($this->newArray, $website->filter('p > a'));
   }// end else
 }
```

after if webpage exist, i´m doing filter with this code:

```
$website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) {

     if($node->text() == $this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"]){
           echo "anchor encontrado: ".$node->text();
      }else{
         echo "ancho a encontrar: " . $this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"];
      }  
       
 });
```

This block it´s into my first `for`. Now i would need compare my `"anchor_text" => "Xamai es partner SAP"` with `$node->text()` from each function... But i don´t know how i can to do this. Also i tryed to write return filter in file, and after build a loop to compare my data with this content, but i have same problem... I need write in file `$node->text()` and `$this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"]`.

It´s important get data by `$this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"]` because it´s my data in `DB`

anybody can help me to build this logic?

**UPDATE**

```
}else{
    $client = new Client();
    $website = $client->request('GET', $data[$i]["post_url"]);
    $website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) use ($i) {

        if($node->text() == $this->allDataLinks[$i]["anchor_text"]){
              echo "anchor encontrado: ".$node->text();
        }else{
          echo "ancho a encontrar: " . $this->allDataLinks[$i]["anchor_text"];
        }  

    });// END EACH FUNCTION
```

}

**update 2, all my code in this function**

```
for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++){
    $file_headers = @get_headers($data[$i]["post_url"]);
    if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || !strpos($file_headers[0],"200")) {
        $exists = false;
        $access_ko[] = $data[$i]["order"];
    }else{
        $client = new Client();
        $website = $client->request('GET', $data[$i]["post_url"]);
        $website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) use ($data, $i) {

             if($node->text() == $data[$i]["anchor_text"]){
                 echo "anchor encontrado: ".$node->text();
             }else{
                echo "anchor a encontrar: " . $data[$i]["anchor_text"];
             }  

          });// END EACH FUNCTION
       }
    }
            
  // delete empty index and order array.
  $order_array = array_filter($this->found_link); 
  $clear_array = array_slice($order_array, 0);

            // loop to compare all data
            for($i=1; $i<count($clear_array); $i++){
                foreach($data as $result){
                    $prueba = ["clear_array" => $clear_array[$i], 'anchor' => $data[$i]["anchor_text"]];
                    array_push($this->result_ok, $prueba);
                    if($clear_array[$i] == $data[$i]["anchor_text"]){
                        //if condition it´s true assign data to array, that will be returned to view or PDF
                        $finalData = [
                            'pedido' => $data[$i]["order"],
                            'articulo'  => $data[$i]["order_name"],
                            'url' => $data[$i]["url"],
                            'post_url' => $data[$i]["post_url"],
                            'anchor_text' => $data[$i]["anchor_text"],
                            'tipo'  => $data[$i]["type_link"],
                            // scraping web result
                            'result_test' => $this->hrefs[$i],
                            'link_rel'  => $this->rels[$i],
                        ];
                        array_push($this->result_ok, $finalData);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $finalData = [
                            'pedido' => $data[$i]["order"],
                            'articulo'  => $data[$i]["order_name"],
                            'url' => $data[$i]["url"],
                            'post_url' => $data[$i]["post_url"],
                            'anchor_text' => $data[$i]["anchor_text"],
                            'tipo'  => $data[$i]["type_link"],
                            // scraping web result
                            'result_test' => $this->hrefs[$i],
                            'link_rel'  => $this->rels[$i],
                        ];
                        $this->result_ko[] = $finalData; 
                        array_push($this->result_ko, $finalData);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                unset($data[$i]);
                break;
            }

            // order data array
            $newData = array_slice($data, 0);

            for($i=0; $i<count($newData); $i++){
                $this->checkPages($newData);
            }
            Log::info(print_r($this->result_ok, true));
            // create associate array to add result_ok and result_ko
            $result = ["result_ok" => $this->result_ok, "result_ko" => $this->result_ko];
```

thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: _"To do this logic, i´m trying this"_ - what are you talking about, you are not even checking on the `url` value in there, which you said was the first thing you need to do - no?

Comment: @CBroe i don´t write my code that verify my URL, but i add now... When i saying ```To do this logic, i´m trying this:``` i mean to next code block... ```$website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) {```....

Comment: _"Now i would need compare my "anchor_text" => "Xamai es partner SAP" with $node->text() from each function... But i don´t know how i can to do this."_ - I would assume that _is_ what `if($node->text() == $this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"])` is supposed to be doing already? If that is not working - then perhaps the node's text content isn't exactly what you were expecting? It might for example contain whitespace before or after the actual text - so the least you should do, is _trim_ this value, before you try to compare it.

Comment: @CBroe i updated my question with my verification. My anchor text in destiny website should be exact... for this i´m trying compare with this if... but if you show my code with more attention, you can see that ```each``` it´s a local function and i can´t access to other variables. i can´t access to $i to loop my data array

Comment: `should be exact`...but **is** it exact? Have you tried to verify that? Don't guess or assume...do a test. Then at least we can rule that issue out, if nothing else.

Comment: @ADyson yes. if you navigate to ```https://mundoejecutivo.com.mx/empresas/empleos-mas-demandados-en-mexico-y-un-enfoque-a-especialistas-en-sap/```and search in this page ```Xamai es partner SAP``` you can show that it´s exact. And i need extract this data

Comment: `i can´t access to other variables`...so you're saying that `$this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"]` isn't accessible inside the `each`? Are you getting a specific error or warning about that?

Comment: _"that each it´s a local function and i can´t access to other variables."_ - `->each(function ($node) use ($otherVariable) { ... }` makes `$otherVariable` accessible within the function.

Comment: @ADyson not, i can´t access to my varaible ```$this->allDataLinks[$j]["anchor_text"]``` return that not exists this variable in log when execute, causing 500 error

Comment: Always give us the _exact_ error message, not a paraphrased version. But anyway CBroe's last comment may help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: @CBroe i don´t understan your response...

Comment: @ADyson i remove all my log to set ```exact error```here... But my error was 500

Comment: @CBroe i need get ```counter``` from my first ```for``` to extract my info from this array. If i do other variable in this loop, i´m doing iterate many times so lenght have ```each function```

Comment: A 500 error always has a precise error message behind it. You said it `return that not exists this variable`...I assume you're trying to describe an error message with this phrase. So what was the real error message?

Comment: Passing a function to another method as a parameter, is called a "callback function". The `each` method will iterate over the links, and then call your callback function - but only with _specified_ set of parameters (specified _by_ the implementation of `each`.) So if you need access to _other_ variables from the outside scope, in your callback function - then you can use the `use` keyword, _as shown_, to make this other variable (or a list of them, separated by comma) available inside the callback function.

Comment: @ADyson Undefined varaible $i

Comment: _"i need get counter from my first for to extract my info from this array"_ - but then you need to do the "extract info from my array" part _inside_ of this loop. If you do it afterwards, then you will only get the _final_ value of `$i`, and that appears to not be what you need here.

Comment: @CBroe i updated my question with my actual code, do you want that i can´t this?

Comment: `array_push($this->newArray, $website->filter('p > a'));` - what is that supposed to be good for? You are fetching the links inside paragraphs here, and stick them into this `newArray` - which I then don't see you doing anything with any more afterwards?

Comment: `Undefined varaible $i`...does your updated code still produce that error inside the `each` callback? I don't see how it could.

Comment: @CBroe yes, i´m getting inside paragraphs links, and add into newArray and after, i wass a loop to get ```text()``` and ```attr```but this solution neither was good because i will to do a loop and access otherwise my array...

Comment: Can you please update the question with your actual code (relevant parts of it, at least), _without_ hacking it into multiple blocks (which leaves us rather guessing as to what the context of each now might be)?

Comment: @CBroe i updated my question in update 2 section, with all my function code, it's not much code

Comment: Okay, and that gives what exact error now? Referring to which line exactly?

Comment: @CBroe with your response ```>each(function ($node) use ($otherVariable) { ... }````  i solve my problem. now my script it´s ok i´m getting 138 result ok of 318. Now have got check this differences why. thanks